# Step into stored procedure - canceled by user

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, debugging, stored-procedures

I am trying to debug a long stored procedure in Visual Studio 2008. I have [followed all the steps on this link](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/debugging-stored-procedures-in-visual-studio-2005), but I still get the same error:

> 'Canceled by user' and it never hits the breakpoint.

Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2005 are running on 2 different servers and domains although I can see the SQL Server from the PC running Visual Studio.

Comment: did you get the answer you were looking for?  If so, could you please accept it?  If not, could you clarify what you are still looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are already on the right track, as that article on sql team is exactly what I would have pointed you to.  Can you verify that you've read and followed the instructions he points you at:

[Setting Up SQL Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4sszxst(VS.80).aspx)

Every single time that I've encountered that lame excuse for an error message, I've found it to be a configuration problem of one sort or another.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server execute `sp_addsrvrolemember '[Domain]\[ID]', 'sysadmin'` to add yourself as a system administrator to the database.

Answer (score 0):

a colleague just got the  'Canceled by user' when Stepping into a Stored Procedure. The solution in this case:

Shift + right click to open Visual Studio as Administrator